# flatpickr: external elements not working while pressing on icon

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I want to use external elements option (wrap). I imagine that if I use this option I'll be able
to open a datepicker by simply pressing on calendar icon but that is not a case. How to make so, that this datepicker would open upon clicking on datepicker icon and on input field?

**Update no.1**

after trial and error session I realized that I was missing wrapping div with a class flatpickr. The case can be closed. (see update for a solution [second datepicker])

**Update no.3**

it is still not fixed. Now it opens a drop menu, however on select field is empty

**Update no.4**

on the third update now it seems to be working. Finally. Needed to add data
attributes (data-toggle and div class flatpickr)

```js
flatpickr($(".input-group.date"), {
  enableTime: false,
  time_24hr: true,
  altInput: true,
  allowInput: true,
  dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
  altFormat: "Y-m-d",
  wrap: true,
  minDate: "2020-01",
  maxDate: "2022-01"
});

//working after adding div with flatpickr class
//opens mnu on pressing icon

$(".flatpickr").flatpickr($(".input-group.date"), {
  enableTime: false,
  time_24hr: true,
  altInput: true,
  allowInput: true,
  dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
  altFormat: "Y-m-d",
  wrap: true,
  minDate: "2020-01",
  maxDate: "2022-01"
});

//working after adding div with flatpickr class
//opens mnu on pressing icon

$(".input-group.date3").flatpickr({
  enableTime: false,
  time_24hr: true,
  altInput: true,
  allowInput: true,
  dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
  altFormat: "Y-m-d",
  wrap: true,
  minDate: "2020-01",
  maxDate: "2022-01"
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>test</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.9/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">
            from
            </label>
            <div class="input-group date">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" data-input/>
               <span class="
                  ">
               <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
               </span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      
      <!--second atempt-->
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">
            from (working correctly)
            </label>
            <div class="flatpickr">
               <div class="input-group date">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" data-input/>
                  <span class="
                     ">
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!--third attempt-->
      <div class="col-sm-12">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">
            from (third time is a charm)
            </label>
            <div class="flatpickr">
               <div class="input-group date3">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" data-input/>
                  <span class="random-class" data-toggle>
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.9/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```